Passing Parameters from ECS to Airflow XCom
I want to create a DAG in Airflow that triggers an ECS task. This ECS task will then return a few parameters to Airflow, allowing the DAG to trigger the next dependent ECS task using those parameters. I’ve been looking for a way to pass these parameters between tasks, and from what I’ve understood, the best approach seems to be using XComs.
However, the EcsRunTaskOperator I’m using doesn’t appear to capture the task’s stdout output (please correct me if I’m wrong). By default, it only passes the ecs_task_arn to XCom. So, I’m wondering how I can achieve this.
I’ve come across an alternative solution where I could read the logs from CloudWatch, parse them, and then push the values to XCom. However, I’m wondering if there’s a better way to do this—something that lets me push values from ECS directly to XCom without involving other services (like S3, message queues, or CloudWatch).
It would be very convenient if the operator could capture ECS stdout and pass the output to XCom, but it doesn’t seem feasible. Any ideas or suggestions?

Capturing from the stdout sounds challenging. Can you edit the ECS task? Just another idea that Airflow DagRun could be triggered from REST API with config too https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run  But on the down side, you need to make sure that the API endpoint is accessible and can be authenticated.

Solution: An Airflow committer got back to me and clarified that the EcsRunTaskOperator actually captures the last log message and pushes it into XCom. However, this wasn’t mentioned in the documentation—they pointed me directly to the code instead.
I managed to solve my issue by setting do_xcom_push = True and configuring the appropriate parameters to fetch the logs from CloudWatch, like this:
awslogs_group=""
awslogs_stream_prefix=""
awslogs_region=""

This allowed me to retrieve the last log message from ECS, which contained the arguments I needed to pass to the next job. With those arguments in XCom, I was able to trigger the next ECS job based on that information.
**I created a PR in Airflow repo so the documentation would be updated soon as well
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs.EcsRunTaskOperator

XCom is a short form of "cross-communications" which communicates between Airflow tasks.
To interact with external system, it is more appropriate to use Airflow REST API. There is a trigger a new DAG run endpoint that you can look into here. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run . It also has conf field where you can put JSON object of your configuration there. Make sure that ECS can authenticate and trigger your Airflow endpoint.
From the API documentation, there are a few API that we can interact with XCom as well. But unfortunately, it's only for get list XCom entries and get an entry itself as XCom should communicate at the task level. Thus, Xcom is not the best choice for your use case.
